# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path

Tags: swift

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid
>   index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}'

I received this error I am guessing i need to do a guard or if let statement to avoid the crash, but where would be the best spot to do such a statement?

```
func observeMessages() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let toId = user?.id else {
            return
        }

        let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid).child(toId)
        userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let messageId = snapshot.key
            let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
            messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    return
                }

                self.messages.append(Message(dictionary: dictionary))
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    //scroll to the last index

                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)

                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

                })

            }, withCancel: nil)

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your index path call? With what values did you call it, what were valid values at the moment of the call?

Comment: let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)

  indexpath should be in optional , let indexPath : IndexPath? = etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code as below...
You are update your `self.message` in background. Take in main thread

```
func observeMessages() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let toId = user?.id else {
        return
    }

    let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid).child(toId)
    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                return
            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.messages.append(Message(dictionary: dictionary))
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                //scroll to the last index

                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)

                self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

            })

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```